# How to SELECT product and sort by discount DESC (PHP,Mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Use PHP and Mysql.
Fields in my table (product) are `id`, `full_price`, `sell_price`, etc.

How can I SELECT products ORDER BY discount DESC, where discount = (full_price-sell_price) * 100 / full_price?  I try to use this, but it doesn't work:

```
  SELECT *
    FROM product 
   WHERE full_price > 0 
ORDER BY (discount = (full_price - sell_price) * 100 / full_price) 
   LIMIT 10
```

Comment: +1 for posting what you tried.  It'd help if you updated your question with the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your `product` table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the discount to be a column in the result set too, do it like this:

```
SELECT *, (full_price - sell_price) * 100 / full_price AS discount
FROM product
WHERE full_price > 0
ORDER BY discount DESC
```

Comment: Which one is faster between Wyzard's solution and Amit Bhargava's solution?

Comment: They're different ways of writing the same thing; they should perform the same.  However, this version sends the discount value back as part of the result set, which means a bit more data is transmitted.  If it were a very large result set and the database server were running on a different machine, network bandwidth could be an issue.

Answer (score 3):

Haven't tried this. But please try

```
SELECT *  FROM product 
WHERE full_price>0 
ORDER BY (full_price-sell_price)*100/full_price LIMIT 10
```